# Install packages from conda channel with url

Tags: python, conda, channel

I want to create a conda channel containing packages that I want to share with some people who should install them. I created a channel with all the packages I want to share and i put that channel in a gitlab repository and use the gitlab pages to make it accessible.

When i try to download a package using
`conda install *url path to the bz2 file of a package*`
it's work, but when i want to use the channel using 
`conda search -c *url path to the channel*` it fails.

I have a json decoding error, here is the last line of the error :

```
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
        obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 185 (char 184)
```

I don't understand what is the problem during the json decoding part and i don't know how to fix it.
Do you guys ever had this problem or know how to fix it ?

Thx